# Finding variance of random variables that are exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, variance, exponential-distribution

Suppose that lifetime of bulb of type n is exponentially distributed with mean value n years, where $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

A bulb is equally likely be chosen from these five types.

(a)  Find the probability that the selected bulb can survive for at least 3 years.

(b)  Find the variance of the lifetime of the selected bulb.

For (a) I split the cases into 5 cases and calculated the $1-P(X<2)$ which equated to $e^{2/n}$ which led to $\sum_{i=1}^{5}0.2 * e^{2/i}$

For (b) I'm not sure how to start, am i supposed to use $Var(X) = 0.2Var(X_1) + 0.2Var(X_2) + ... + 0.2Var(X_5)$ since they have independent lifetimes.

Comment: Why do you have $e^{2/n}$ (which is $>1$ so not a probability) rather than $e^{-3/n}$?

Comment: @Henry Yep i just changed it! I had a error in my working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use the law of total variance, which would give  $\frac{1+4+9+16+25}{5} + 2$, then an alternative approach here is:

- The mean of $X_n$ is $n$ and the variance of $X_n$ is $n^2$, so $E[X_n^2]=2n^2$.
- You can average the means for your mixture distribution so $E[X]=\frac{1+2+3+4+5}5=3$.
- You cannot simply average the variances but you can average the $E[X_n^2]$ to get $E[X^2]=\frac{2+8+18+32+50}{5}=22$.
- That gives $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=22-9=13$ for your mixture distribution.

Comment: hi! does exponential distribution not matter in this case for the mean value?

Comment: The mean of the mixture of is the mean of the means $1,2,3,4,5$ so in that sense the shape of the distributions do not matter once you known their means

Comment: Alright! I think i understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be the uniform random variable indicating which among the five types is selected. $$N\sim\mathcal U\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Exp}(1/N)$$

---

**(a)** Exponential distributions are continuous,  So the complement of lasting at least 3 years is **lasting less than 3 years**, rather than lasting less than 2 years.

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\geqslant 3) &= \mathsf E\big(1-\mathsf P(X\lt 3\mid N)\big)\\&= \mathsf E(\mathrm e^{-3/N})\\ &= \tfrac 15\sum_{n=0}^5\mathrm e^{-3/n}\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$

---

**(b)** Use the Law of Total Variance.

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(X) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid N))+ \mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid N))\\ &=\mathsf E(N^2)+\mathsf{Var}(N)\\ &~~\vdots\end{align}$

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what Law of Total Variance is since I did not learn that, is the alternative approach from @Annika applicable?

Comment: @Catt No.  The Total Variance is not *just* the Expectation of  Variance. $$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X) & =\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^2\mid N))-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid N))^2\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid  N))+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid N)^2)-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid N))^2\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid N))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid N))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Which obtains the same answer as @Henry did , btw,

Comment: Alright! Thank you :)